# How do I reset countdown counter in react?

Tags: javascript, countdown

I want reset the countdown counter, I wrote "  countdownStatus === COUNTDOWNSTATUS.reset && countdownTimer !== 0 && clearTimeout(() => setCountdownTimer(countdownTimer === 0))"

It only stops counting. But not reset...

Could someone helps me? Thanks

```
import './App.css';
import { useState } from 'react'
import { useEffect } from 'react';

const COUNTDOWNSTATUS = {
  pause: 0,
  start: 1,
  default: 2,
  reset: 3
}


function App() {

  let [countdownTimer, setCountdownTimer] = useState(60)


  const [countdownStatus, setCountdownStatus] = useState(COUNTDOWNSTATUS.default);
 
  const handelClickCountdownStart = () => setCountdownStatus(COUNTDOWNSTATUS.start);
  const handelClickCountdownPause = () => setCountdownStatus(COUNTDOWNSTATUS.pause);
  const handelClickCountdownReset = () => setCountdownStatus(COUNTDOWNSTATUS.reset);

 
  useEffect(() => {
    countdownStatus === COUNTDOWNSTATUS.start && countdownTimer > 0 && setTimeout(() => setCountdownTimer(countdownTimer - 1), 1000)
    countdownStatus === COUNTDOWNSTATUS.pause && countdownTimer !== 0 && clearTimeout()
    countdownStatus === COUNTDOWNSTATUS.reset && countdownTimer !== 0 && clearTimeout(() => setCountdownTimer(countdownTimer === 0))

  
  })

  return (
    <div className="App">

      <h1>Countdown Timer</h1>
      <h1>{countdownTimer}</h1>
      <button onClick={handelClickCountdownStart}>Start</button>
      <button onClick={handelClickCountdownPause}>Pause</button>
      <button onClick={handelClickCountdownReset}>Reset</button>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: move your useEffect functions to their  specific handleClick functions (no need to use useEffect). just trigger functions on handleClickPause or Reset or Start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code.

First, you should implement a dependencie array with the `countdownStatus` variable, since it's the one you are looking at.

Secondly, you should use `setInterval` for this situation, and store it's reference to clear the interval on pause, reset or counter reaching 0. Something like this:

```
import './App.css';
import { useState } from "react";
import { useEffect } from "react";

const COUNTDOWNSTATUS = {
  pause: 0,
  start: 1,
  default: 2,
  reset: 3
};
let intervalId = null;
function App() {
  let [countdownTimer, setCountdownTimer] = useState(60);

  const [countdownStatus, setCountdownStatus] = useState(
    COUNTDOWNSTATUS.default
  );

  const handelClickCountdownStart = () =>
    setCountdownStatus(COUNTDOWNSTATUS.start);
  const handelClickCountdownPause = () =>
    setCountdownStatus(COUNTDOWNSTATUS.pause);
  const handelClickCountdownReset = () =>
    setCountdownStatus(COUNTDOWNSTATUS.reset);

  useEffect(() => {
    switch (countdownStatus) {
      case COUNTDOWNSTATUS.start:
        intervalId = setInterval(() => {
          setCountdownTimer((prevValue) => {
            const newValue = prevValue - 1;
            if (newValue <= 0) clearInterval(intervalId);
            return newValue;
          });
        }, 1000);
        break;
      case COUNTDOWNSTATUS.pause:
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        break;
      case COUNTDOWNSTATUS.reset:
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        setCountdownTimer(60);
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }, [countdownStatus]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Countdown Timer</h1>
      <h1>{countdownTimer}</h1>
      <button onClick={handelClickCountdownStart}>Start</button>
      <button onClick={handelClickCountdownPause}>Pause</button>
      <button onClick={handelClickCountdownReset}>Reset</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```